One-liner double zugzwang
Can you construct a position on a single file (double your points if it is the a or h file, triple if position is symmetric) which is a mutual full point zugzwang?

The full-point precision in the body of the question is important. For an half-point double-zugzwang, Ke5 Pe4 vs Ke7 would do.

It's possible in some variants such as giveaway.

It should be possible to check all positions with 4-7 men all on 1 file using tablebases.

@Lucenaposition: It just came to me that all full point double zugzwangs with at least 6 men (not sure about 7) were tabulated in some study magazine, if my memory serves me well. The theme is well researched, see e.g. here for my 1st google hit: https://www.chess.com/blog/Rocky64/even-more-adventures-with-endgame-tablebases

It's a good question, and I would like to lay claim to the view that no such position exists.
I have explored a bit, and found no hint of necessary zugzwang behaviour. Without exhaustive computer search, however, it's difficult to prove.
